# Programmatically adding Beans to Spring application Context

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am trying to add a simple String to my Spring Application Context, and then autowire this to a different existing bean (A) within the application context. I know this is not the usual way to go, yet I need to add many beans programmatically, which would otherwise make my xml configuration huge.

```
public class MyPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, Ordered {

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    beanFactory.registerSingleton("myString", "this is the String");
    A a = beanFactory.getBean(A.class);
    beanFactory.autowireBean(a);
  }
}    

public class A {

    @Autowired 
    public transient String message;

}
```

When running this, the property `message` of the instance of A is null. What am I missing?

EDIT: this is my application context:

```
@Configuration
class TestConfig {

  @Bean 
  public A a() {
    return new A();
  }

  @Bean
  public MyPostProcessor postProcessor() {
    return new MyPostProcessor();
  }

}
```

And this is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class MyTest {

  @Autowired 
  private transient A a;

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    System.err.println("Running");
    System.err.println("This is the autowired String: " + a.message);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not instantiate beans from `BeanFactoryPostprocessors`.
From `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` JavaDoc:

> A BeanFactoryPostProcessor may interact with and modify bean
>   definitions, but never bean instances. Doing so may cause premature
>   bean instantiation, violating the container and causing unintended
>   side-effects.

In your case, the `A` bean is instantiated before `BeanPostProcessors` and  therefore not autowired.

Remove the lines:

```
A a = beanFactory.getBean(A.class);
beanFactory.autowireBean(a);
```

And will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@Qualifier` to specific which bean you want to Auto wire.

```
public class A {

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("myString")
    public transient String message;

}
```